# jquery onClick not firing in wordpress. Works as a .html page

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is the code I'm using to create an application page. It works perfectly fine offline when running it as a .html file through FireFox, but doesn't work when I upload it to WordPress.

I believe the Javascript is not being executed onclick, but I cannot find fault within it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    .wrapper {width: 100%;
        border: black 1px solid;}
        .mItem {width: 14%;
            float: left;
            border: white 1px solid;
            height: 60px;
            color: #ffffff;
            background-color: #dddddd;
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: middle;
            line-height: 60px;   
            display:block;
        }
        #mItem1 {background-color: #FFA500;}

        .EFcontent{
            width: 100%;
            color: black;
        }
        .contentwrap {width: 100%;}
        #view1 {display: block;}
        #view2 {display: none;}
        #view3 {display: none;}
        #view4 {display: none;}
        #view5 {display: none;}
        #view6 {display: none;}
        #view7 {display: none;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="path">
                <div id="mItem1" class="mItem">Student Details</div>
                <div id="mItem2" class="mItem">Employer Details</div>
                <div id="mItem3" class="mItem">Employment Details</div>
                <div id="mItem4" class="mItem">Education History</div>
                <div id="mItem5" class="mItem">Nationality</div>
                <div id="mItem6" class="mItem">Disability</div>
                <div id="mItem7" class="mItem">General</div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="contentwrap">
                <div id="view1" class="EFcontent">
                    <h3>Student Details</h3>

                    <a onclick="page2()" href="#2">Next</a>
                </div>
                <div id="view2" class="EFcontent">
                    <p>content2</p>
                    <a onclick="page1()" href="#2">Back</a>
                    <a onclick="page3()" href="#3">Next</a>
                </div>
                <div id="view3" class="EFcontent">
                    <p>content3</p>
                    <a onclick="page2()" href="#3">Back</a>
                    <a onclick="page4()" href="#4">Next</a>
                </div>
                <div id="view4" class="EFcontent">
                    <p>content4</p>
                    <a onclick="page3()" href="#4">Back</a>
                    <a onclick="page5()" href="#5">Next</a>
                </div>
                <div id="view5" class="EFcontent">
                    <p>content5</p>
                    <a onclick="page4()" href="#5">Back</a>
                    <a onclick="page6()" href="#6">Next</a>
                </div>
                <div id="view6" class="EFcontent">
                    <p>content6</p>
                    <a onclick="page5()" href="#6">Back</a>
                    <a onclick="page7()" href="#7">Next</a>
                </div>
                <div id="view7" class="EFcontent">
                    <p>content7</p>
                    <a onclick="page6()" href="#7">Back</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(init);
        function init(){

            function clear() {
                document.getElementById('view1').style.display = 'none'; 
                document.getElementById('mItem1').style.backgroundColor = '#dddddd';
                document.getElementById('view2').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('mItem2').style.backgroundColor = '#dddddd';
                document.getElementById('view3').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('mItem3').style.backgroundColor = '#dddddd';
                document.getElementById('view4').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('mItem4').style.backgroundColor = '#dddddd';
                document.getElementById('view5').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('mItem5').style.backgroundColor = '#dddddd';
                document.getElementById('view6').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('mItem6').style.backgroundColor = '#dddddd';
                document.getElementById('view7').style.display = 'none'; 
                document.getElementById('mItem7').style.backgroundColor = '#dddddd';
            }
            function page1() {clear(); document.getElementById('view1').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('mItem1').style.backgroundColor = '#FFA500';}
            function page2() {clear(); document.getElementById('view2').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('mItem2').style.backgroundColor = '#FFA500';}
            function page3() {clear(); document.getElementById('view3').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('mItem3').style.backgroundColor = '#FFA500';}
            function page4() {clear(); document.getElementById('view4').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('mItem4').style.backgroundColor = '#FFA500';}
            function page5() {clear(); document.getElementById('view5').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('mItem5').style.backgroundColor = '#FFA500';}
            function page6() {clear(); document.getElementById('view6').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('mItem6').style.backgroundColor = '#FFA500';}
            function page7() {clear(); document.getElementById('view7').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('mItem7').style.backgroundColor = '#FFA500';}
        }
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8LZNa/4/)

Comment: I accidentally used the wrong title...

Comment: Still learning the ways of stackflow. Teach me Obi-Cerbrus Kenobi, you're my only hope.

Comment: Below the tags in your question, there's an _"edit"_ link.

Comment: You didn't include jQuery in the code above.

Comment: Oh, there it is, I was looking through my profile page.

Comment: "document).ready(init)" very uban. yeah you need to include jquery in the page **before** you call the `$(document` code

Comment: Ignore the fiddle @Dr.Molle

Comment: Do you have any kind of errors? When you inspect the page, are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Thanks @atmd, I'm guessing anything with a '$' is using the JQuery Library?

Comment: yep, that's right (or it could use `jQuery` instead, which in wordpress is often to avoid conflicts

Comment: @dingo_d Yeah, The log says, "ReferenceError: page2 is not defined"

Comment: @atmd The code I'm using is 

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.tempweb.com/wp-content/uploads/jquery-1.11.3.min_.js"></script>

Comment: You could just write your javascript in an external file, and enqueue it in your `functions.php` file. Also you don't need to call on external jquery when you have it in wordpress. In your `functions.php` put this `wp_enqueue_script( 'scripts', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/scripts.js', array( 'jquery' ),'', true );` And in your js folder create a scripts.js file with your code inside...

Comment: Aside from "$(document).ready(init); function init(){}," where else am I using jquery?

Comment: Is there an alternative to onclick that would?

Comment: @ChristianCugnet Where's the `onclick` event? I can't seem to find it in your Fiddle. Your Fiddle and code above are completely different!

Comment: @AbraarArique Ignore the fiddle link, I accidentally included it. It should have been edited out.

Comment: @ChristianCugnet What is your log saying? Any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here.

Firstly jquery isnt included, but thats fine because you are not using it really, you dont need that `$(document` line.

Your code can't find the `page1` . . . `page7` functions, which is why you are getting errors (masked by the `cant find $` error.)

All you need to do is remove the `$(document` as you arnt using it, and get rid of you `init` method, like [this](http://atmd83.jsbin.com/lelori/edit?html,console,output).

(jsfiddle with `init` and `$(document` removed)

Comment: Works, thanks for all the help guys. This community is awesome.

Part of the problem was Wordpress adding '<p>' tags to the code.